# Django Models - Problem using ManyToManyField add() method

Tags: django-models

I have a problem using the add() method below...

```
class JobRecord(models.Model):
    """JobRecord model"""

    project             = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    date                = models.DateField()
    supervisor          = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='supervisor_set')

    operators           = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='operators_set', help_text='Include the supervisor as an operator here also.')

    vehicles            = models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s" % (self.project.name,  self.date.strftime('%b %d'))

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(JobRecord, self).save(**kwargs)
        if not self.operators.filter(pk=self.supervisor.pk):
            self.operators.add(self.supervisor)
            print self.operators.values()
```

Strangely, the `print self.operators.values()` line displays the correct values, however, upon inspection of the record in django admin, the supervisor has not been saved as an operator.

ie.

```
self.operators.add(self.supervisor) # fails to commit
```

What manner of magic do I need here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I even set up a post_save signal and couldn't get the add() method to stick.  Neither side of my ManyToMany uses their default autonumber id.  I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

I randomly found this question so maybe is not actual, but you should save self.supervisor first:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    super(JobRecord, self).save(**kwargs)
    if not self.operators.filter(pk=self.supervisor.pk):
        self.supervisor.save()
        self.operators.add(self.supervisor)
        print self.operators.values()
```